# Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE in

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to follow [Spring Boot tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-pom) to create my first Spring boot application. However, as usual something goes wrong.
When I follow the instruction to create a new pom for spring boot project I get the following error.

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.XXXX:rabbitmq-poc:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/home/adelin/workspace/rabbitmq-poc/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, /home/adelin/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 1426, column 16 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I've tried to force update my local repo with `mvn clean install -U` but with no success.

Any ideas ?

Comment: 2.1.3.RELEASE looks a suspicious version, don't you rather want to use 4.1.3.RELEASE ?

Comment: Well I copied it directly from the tutorial.

Comment: See the _Appendix E. Dependency versions_, it looks like 4.1.3.RELEASE is used.